# Menu Underline shows without Hover after adding subitems

Tags: menus, css

One of my client's site has a blue underline when we hover on the menu item. As the client added a sub-item to the "Services" menu item, the underline under the services menu item started appearing without even hovering. I want the line to appear only when the user hovers on the menu item. Here's the site URL.

**More Information**

Wordpress default menus are being used.
Check the other menu items, when you hover only then the line appears.
When I inspect the element, as I remove the "current-menu-ancestor" subclass from this menu item it starts working perfectly as I want. How can I remove this class? Or any alternative solution?
I have tried removing the "current-menu-ancestor" subclass from the theme's style.css file but it has no effect.
The theme being used is "Salient" Wordpress theme.

Answer (score -1):

.nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {text-decoration:none} will help. Alternatively, use .nav-menu .current-menu-ancestor > a {text-decoration:none !important;}.
Please change the .nav-menu with the class name that you have used

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you but I solved the issue myself. It was due to some issues with the link which was added to the sub-items of the menu.